# Underfull \vboxes, why are lines with their footnotes pushed to next page?

Tags: spacing, footnotes, memoir

How to avoid underfull \vboxes in places with lots of long footnotes and relatively less text, where latex pushes a line to the next page because of the footnotes in it? Is there a way to allow it to pull more text to the preceding page, even if that means that footnote marker and footnote will need to be rendered on different pages?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
Text\footnote{\lipsum[1]}, some more text,\footnote{\lipsum[2]} 
and yet a bit more more text\footnote{\lipsum[3]}.
Text\footnote{\lipsum[1]}, some more text,\footnote{\lipsum[2]} 
and yet a bit more more text\footnote{\lipsum[3]}.
Text\footnote{\lipsum[1]}, some more text,\footnote{\lipsum[2]} 
and yet a bit more more text\footnote{\lipsum[3]}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Because a footnote marker should land on the same page as the footnote.

Comment: @egreg So then the solution will have to be to reformulate text and footnotes such that the marker(s) will be further up in the text I suppose?

Comment: You can clearly see that an additional line in the first page needs space for footnotes 5 to 8 and this is not available. It's the same problem as squeezing an elephant in a suitcase. `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do this you can separate the footnotes from their marks, but it may be pretty confusing for your readers.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

Text\footnote{\lipsum[1]}, some more text,\footnote{\lipsum[2]} 
and yet a bit more more text\footnote{\lipsum[3]}.
Text\footnote{\lipsum[1]}, some more text,\footnotemark
and yet a bit more more text\footnotemark.
Text\footnotemark, some more text,\footnotemark
and yet a bit more more text\footnotemark.%

\clearpage
\footnotetext[5]{\lipsum[2]}% 
\footnotetext[6]{\lipsum[1]}%
\footnotetext[7]{\lipsum[3]}%
\footnotetext[8]{\lipsum[2]}%
\footnotetext[9]{\lipsum[3]}%

\end{document}
```